# FFMPEG - Loop Video and Play Audio from playlist

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming

I decided to start a side project where I wanted to learn more about ffmpeg due to the whole StayAtHome situation going on at the moment, but after reading tons of articles and trying a million different solutions, sadly, I hit a wall. That is why if someone could help me I would be really grateful. My initial idea was to create a stream, which will consists of two different inputs, where one would be for video and one for audio. The video file would act as a background so it will be a single file that I want to loop and the audio file would play from a playlist of audio files and when it reaches the last audio file it will start from the beginning. I managed to solve some of the steps required for the end result, but I am stuck and I don't really know how to loop the video and audio outputs.

So far I learnt that you can combine video and audio by using the following code:

`ffmpeg -i ~/Desktop/stream/video.mp4 -i ~/Desktop/stream/audio.mp3`

I also tried creating a text file and link to it - `-i ~/Desktop/stream/video.txt` where inside on new lines I pasted multiple lines of the path to the same video - `path '~/Desktop/stream/video.mp4' but the stream ended immediately leading me to think that the video was not called at all and it just read the txt file and stopped.

Another way I tried to solve this was including the 'loop=loop=-1:size=1:start=0' but I got the following error - `No such filter: 'loop'.` I also found a function called `stream_loop -1`, but that did not work either and gave the following error - `Unrecognized option: stream_loop=-1`.

So far my full code is:

`ffmpeg -i ~/Desktop/stream/video.mp4 -i ~/Desktop/stream/audio.mp3 -c:v libx264 -async 1 -vsync 1 -preset fast -pix_fmt yuv420p -s 1024x768 -threads 0 -f flv "rtmp://url"`

Best regards,
George

Comment: Share the full log of `ffmpeg -i ~/Desktop/stream/video.mp4 -i ~/Desktop/stream/audio.mp3`

Comment: @Gyan, I am not sure if you are asking for the entire code or just this, because if you are asking just for the snippet in your comment I have not tested it. If you refer to the whole snippet I can provide you with the log.